# hugo theme with netlify cms white admin page error

Tags: netlify, hugo, netlify-cms

My problem is when I try to connect the HUGO  theme with Netlify cms, using an official Netlify guide and also 1 blog on [how to connect Hugo with netlify cms](https://dev.to/howtocode_io/how-to-build-a-jamstack-blog-with-hugo-netlify-cms-and-zapier-14dc), when I try to open website/admin then I always get page not found. After adding java snippets in the partials footer.html file, now the cms page is opening but it shows a totally blank page without showing any errors.
Can you tell me what to change as i am new to this and its really confusing to configure  netlify cms with ssg themes
I have added two files admin/index.html and admin/config.yml in static folder but still I am not able to authenticate netlify cms with my theme

Github repo i am using: https://github.com/h-enk/henkverlinde.com

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your `/static` folder should contain an `admin` subfolder, in which a [config file](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/) and an [index page](https://www.kevinsahin.com/blog/adding-netlify-cms-to-an-existing-hugo-website/) should be.